# Get unambiguous time format from MySqlDateTime in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

For my MySql insert I have to get the unambiguous `DATETIME` format. Therefore I used the MySqlDateTime class.

However when I want to retrieve the string for the sql command it returns the datetime in the format `DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS` and not in the required `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]` format.

I there a way to retrieve the correct datetime format without writing a custom function as this seems a bit clumsy?

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.Types;

static void Main()
{
    var time = new MySqlDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow);
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString());
}
```

Comment: If you want a particular format from .ToString, you have to tell it what that format is, e.g. `time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")`.

Comment: The MySqlDateTime class doesn't support any arguments in `.ToString()` though.

Comment: Convert it back to DateTime using MySqlDateTime.GetDateTime() and use the returned value to format the string.

Comment: Ok, and in which cases should you use the MySqlDateTime then?

Comment: Just when inserting and retrieving to and from the database/